# Storing arugement of function from within function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Try it

Try it again

JAVASCRIPT

```
var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

function checkAdult(age) {
return age >= 18;
}

function myFunction(dd) {
dd=dd.filter(checkAdult)
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dd.filter(checkAdult);
}
function myFunction1() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ages
}
```

try it button will give me [32.33.40] after that when i press "try it" again button , i don't get [32,33,40] instead i get [32,33,16,40] , Could i get [32,33,40] from second button, when it is clicked after first button

Comment: Why are you passing `dd` into the function in which you're declaring, and calculating, it? And as far as your question goes - bearing in mind I may have misunderstood it in some way - if `z` and the function are within the same scope you can simply update the variable within the function with `z = newValueForZ`.

Comment: Have updated and refactored your question, but still couldn't understand what you need.

Comment: Simply to `return dd` and call it like `z = myFunction(…)`

Comment: I just wanted to use the function to define another variable A and B in same way as for z and update them from within same function as :
var z = [];
var b =[]
function myFunction(x, y, dd) {
    var dd = x * y;
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dd;
}
/// where dd could be z or b

Comment: What do you mean by "define another variable A and B in the same way as for z". What are you actually trying to achieve here? I can't really understand the problem but maybe if you can explain what you are trying to do with the code ...

Comment: Well, I tested your code and after clicking each button twice, I got [3,3] and [5,5], so where is the pbl ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass `z` as an argument if it is available in the outer scope.

```js
var z = 0
function myFunction(x, y) {
  console.log('z before', z)
  z = x * y
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = z
  console.log('z after', z)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction(2,3)">2*3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction(4,5)">4*5</button>

<div id="demo">0</div>
```

As you can see, `z` in the outer scope will be updated from within `myFunction`.

Comment: I just wanted to use the function to define another variable A and B in same way as for z and update them from within same function as :
var z = [];
var b =[]
function myFunction(x, y, dd) {
    var dd = x * y;
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = dd;
}
/// where dd could be z or b